# When am trying to execute the alter script. Getting connection lost error in MySql

Tags: mysql

When am trying to execute the below query from workbench. Getting connection lost error.

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name ADD (
CONSTRAINT PK_Nam
PRIMARY KEY
(ID_EMP, ID_DEPT));
```

Can you please help, why this error is happening.? Same am trying to execute from toad. it is working fine.

Comment: are you trying using a root user?

Comment: No. Am not trying using root user and also if I tried this same alter in different MySQL server it is working fine.. I checked the versions also. No difference in that

Comment: There might be clues in the mysql error log on the server

Comment: if you have root credentials check  " alter  table " using root, if  you don't have root credentials then check your current user permissions " show grants for 'username'@'%'; " and verify the permission for that particular mysql user

Comment: If I removed the bracket after the ADD then it is working fine I.e. Alter table tab_name Add constraint pk_nam primary key (id_emp, id_dept);

Comment: @Vatev ok.. I will get the server log Nd will check